# Android display image from URL

Tags: android, image, url

How can I load image from below url .
http://images.google.com/hosted/life/l?imgurl=46d75bbfa52a8450

I use Google Custom Search API to search image from site [images.google.com](http://images.google.com) .
It will return a json file with contents of link tag . Example : http://images.google.com/hosted/life/l?imgurl=46d75bbfa52a8450 . And I want to load it to my view .

If URL is endwith file extends ".jpg or .png", i can download and display it . 
But if not , i can get the image .
Anyone can help me .

Comment: Are you trying to load the image into an ImageView? Can you post the contents of the JSON response?

Answer (score 1):

Hi Please used below code.

```
  String url = "http://images.google.com/hosted/life/l?imgurl=46d75bbfa52a8450";
    InputStream ins = null;
    try {
        ins = new java.net.URL(url).openStream();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FlushedInputStream(ins));
    imageview.setImageBitmap(b);

 static class FlushedInputStream extends FilterInputStream {
    public FlushedInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {
        super(inputStream);
    }

    @Override
    public long skip(long n) throws IOException {
        long totalBytesSkipped = 0L;
        while (totalBytesSkipped < n) {
            long bytesSkipped = in.skip(n - totalBytesSkipped);
            if (bytesSkipped == 0L) {
                int b = read();
                if (b < 0) {
                    break; // we reached EOF
                } else {
                    bytesSkipped = 1; // we read one byte
                }
            }
            totalBytesSkipped += bytesSkipped;
        }
        return totalBytesSkipped;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for give me this code . But when I run it . It throws an error SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null.