# Android ImageView image display problem where the image downloaded from web

Tags: android, android-imageview

I use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6489780/android-display-image-from-url) to download image from web. The image is normally displays on web. Here is the [link](http://www.mekanist.net/img/places/75/faros_20110909125521412.jpg) of the Image. It downloads on Android device successfully but not displaying on an ImageView control. And [this Image](http://www.mekanist.net/img/places/75/faros_20110325143125765.jpg) downloads and showing successfully. What can be causes some specific images can't be showen by Android ImageView control?

Android API Level: 7

Thank you!

Comment: When I tried to download the image from web. I see InputStream is not null but a property of InputStream wrappedstream is null so BitmapFactory cannot decode the stream.

Comment: And there is a interesting thing when I save the image on the web server via photoshop or by custom application it works very well. But there are a lot of images that can't resize all.

Comment: I wrote a a peace of code to resave the image on the server and let to know client to redownload it. The problem was all images have broken data because of the resize lib has already used.

Answer (score 2):

This image cannot be displayed in Android Browser: 
http://www.mekanist.net/img/places/75/faros_20110909125521412.jpg

This problem may be caused by unsupported details of jpeg image format.
You should consider to investigate the thumb-maker code.

Comment: So I have to research about this problem! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Drawable img = Drawable.createFromPath(filePath);
```

filePath is the image you downloaded on your phone sdcard absolute path

```
ImageView ivPic=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivPic);;    
ivPic.setImageDrawable(img);
```

Comment: Sorry, there are a lot of image so i don't want to save in local storage of the phone.